# Solving simultaneous equation for discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

equation 1: `0 = x + y`

equation 2: `1 = xr + ys`

Where `r = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`, and `s = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2`

my approach is to set equation 2 to `0 = xr + ys - 1` . Then, `xr + ys -1 = x + y`

Im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: How about you use $y=-x$ from equation 1. Then what happens if you put this into equation 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} x+y=0 \\ xr+ys=1\end{cases}$$

$x+y=0\implies x=-y$. Substitute this in for $y$ in the second equation. $$xr-xs=1\implies x=\dfrac{1}{r-s}$$

Since $y=-x \implies y=\dfrac{-1}{r-s}$. Hence $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left(\dfrac{1}{r-s}, \dfrac{-1}{r-s}\right)$ is the solution.